# Is there a difference between transform and transformation?

Tags: definition, transformation, laplace-transform

I was told that there is a difference between a transform and a transformation. Can anyone point out clearly?

For example, is Laplace transform not a transformation?

Comment: Don't believe there is a difference between the two notions.

Comment: Ask the person who told you.

Comment: Perhaps the answer by Christian Blatter makes sense. Then "transform" stands for the "transformation" or the "transformed" respectively; I am not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A *transformation* is certainly a process. The word "transform" can be used as short for "transfomation", but also for a transformed object. An example for the first usage is

"The Fourier transform is an automorphism of the Schwartz space ${\cal S}\,$",

an example for the second usage is

"The Laplace transform of $t\mapsto e^{\lambda t}$ $\>(t\geq0)$ is $s\mapsto{\displaystyle{1\over s-\lambda}}\>$".

Comment: While both are the same, it seems to me that the Wikipedia article of [transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_(function)) discusses more on geometry, while [transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_transforms) is not

Answer (score 2):

From the accepted question on ELU: [Transform or transformation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/5456/80007)

> In the particular domain you're referencing, both transform and
>   transformation have an established history of usage.
>
> For example, we speak of the Hough transform or the Fourier transform.
>   We also talk about affine transformations or homothetic
>   transformations.
>
> I'm not aware of any specific rules, but in general, I've noticed that
>   "named" objects tend to be referenced as the foo transform, while
>   unnamed or otherwise generic ones use the foo transformation.

Answer (score 1):

To my mind (a mathematical physicist), a transform is a specific kind of transformation, namely, a transformation not of values, but of functions. So, a transformation $N$ maps a value $x$ onto its image value:

$N: x \to N(x)$

whereas the transform $M$ maps a function $f$ onto its image function:

$M: f(x) \to F(y)$

The reason we call the Fourier transform a *transform* is because, although it is indeed a transformation, it is in particular a transformation of functions, since it maps an entire function $f(x)$ onto its frequency spectrum $F(p)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solidly common-usage question, which I was asked many decades ago, and has now come up again.

In common usage, when referring to the alteration of elements of a set, as an abstraction, (or as Niall says, a "process"), the word *transformation* is always applied.  The set is *transformed*, action is a *transformation*.

When referring to the transformation itself as an object, as a thing that performs the transformation, the word *transform* is often applied.  (This includes the "named" transformations that Ooker refers to.)  But clearly, there is a direct correspondence here between the action and the actor --- it could be viewed as a matter of emphasis.

But the terminology isn't cut-and-dried at all.

P.S. The terms *operator* and *transform* are usually restricted to mappings whose range and domain are homomorphic.  These are used in very much the same way, except, I don't think I've ever seen *transform* applied to mappings of finite-dimensional spaces.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be many definitions, but I particularly like the one from the Oxford Dictionary of English (available in the Dictionary app on macOS):

> transform: the product of a transformation

Unfortunately, I can't find this online, but [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transform) has a similar definition:

> a mathematical element obtained from another by transformation